# How to set up relationship with JPA for keeping track of video viewing records

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm currently doing a project which has multiple programs and programs have multiple videos, so I set up my Program and ProgramVideo entities like this.

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "program")
public class Program extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    //other fields I'm using

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProgramVideo> programVideo = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "program_video")
public class ProgramVideo extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    //other fields I'm using

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "programVideo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<VideoRecordHistory> videoRecordHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here I didn't add an @ManyToOne relationship inside **ProgramVideo** Entity because I didn't think I need to get **Program** information from **ProgramVideo** side.

With the **ProgramVideo** and **Program** entities set up, I wanted to implement a way to keep track of whether users started watching the video and up to what point they watched the video to.

To implement this function, I decided to make APIs for

1. Create an entry in VideoRecordHistory table to indicate whether the user started/clicked to watched a specific video.
2. Update the created entry from time to time with the information of which point in time the video is being played at.

The VideoRecordHistory entity/table looks like the following.

```
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "video_record_history")
public class VideoRecordHistory extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "program_video_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private ProgramVideo programVideo;

    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long memberId;

    @Column(name = "video_length")
    private String videoLength;

    @Column(name = "watched_to")
    private String watchedTo;
}
```

With the first API, an entry is created with the programVideoId, memberId, and the videoLength.

One thing to remember is that I didn't add any relation between this table and my member table as it would create a circular relation due to the fact that it may cause stack overflow.

---

### Problem

So a user registers to a program and clicks the program to view the list of program_videos with the progression(from VideoRecordHistory table) of each video.

By nature the relation between ProgramVideo <-> VideoRecordHistory would be **OneToMany** since I won't be creating a table for each user's video history. I want to keep track of all the records using programVideoId and memberId in one table.
Since it's OneToMany and set up as the following,

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "programVideo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<VideoRecordHistory> videoRecordHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

when I use this following query

```
    public List<ProgramVideo> getProgramVideoListAndProgressByProgramAndMember(Long programId, Long memberId) {
        return queryFactory
                .select(programVideo)
                .from(programVideo)
                .leftJoin(videoRecordHistory)
                .on(programVideo.eq(videoRecordHistory.programVideo))
                .where(
                        programVideo.program.id.eq(programId),
                        videoRecordHistory.memberId.eq(memberId)
                )
                .fetch();
    }
```

it always expects a list of videoRecordHistory **AND** gives me record of all the user without filtering out specific member using this line

```
                        videoRecordHistory.memberId.eq(memberId)
```

Another query I tried was

```
    public List<ProgramVideo> getProgramVideoListAndProgressByProgramAndMember(Long programId, Long memberId) {
        return queryFactory
                .select(programVideo)
                .from(programVideo)
                .leftJoin(videoRecordHistory)
                .on(programVideo.eq(videoRecordHistory.programVideo)
                        .and(videoRecordHistory.memberId.eq(memberId))
                )
                .where(
                        programVideo.program.id.eq(programId)
                )
                .fetch();
    }
```

which adds the videoRecordHistory member restraint inside the 'ON' clause.
This gave me the same result as the previous query with all the member's video history record...

## Question

I want to get the List of ProgramVideo using ProgramId, with the progression of the specific user, using memberId.

1. I cannot figure out if my usage of Querydsl is wrong

**OR**

2. I cannot figure out if my entity set up is ineffective and needs a fix.

I think having VideoRecordHistory as a List inside Programvideo entity is causing the problem, forcing the result to always be a list, but also, even with the memberId restraint, I'm still getting records of all the members.

## Updates

Original Query:

```
2023-12-20T14:25:50.671+09:00 DEBUG 99522 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.created_at,
        p1_0.created_id,
        p1_0.day_count,
        p1_0.has_assignment,
        p1_0.media_url,
        p1_0.program_id,
        p1_0.title,
        p1_0.updated_at,
        p1_0.updated_id,
        p1_0.video_point,
        p1_0.video_summary,
        p1_0.video_thumbnail 
    from
        program_video p1_0 
    left join
        video_record_history v1_0 
            on p1_0.id=v1_0.program_video_id 
            and v1_0.member_id=? 
    where
        p1_0.program_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.created_at,
        p1_0.created_id,
        p1_0.day_count,
        p1_0.has_assignment,
        p1_0.media_url,
        p1_0.program_id,
        p1_0.title,
        p1_0.updated_at,
        p1_0.updated_id,
        p1_0.video_point,
        p1_0.video_summary,
        p1_0.video_thumbnail 
    from
        program_video p1_0 
    left join
        video_record_history v1_0 
            on p1_0.id=v1_0.program_video_id 
            and v1_0.member_id=? 
    where
        p1_0.program_id=?
```

Comment: Please turn on `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` on `application.properties` and check generated query after it runs the method. You can try to run it on db & post the result on post.

Comment: @phuongnq1995 dam.. Just from your comment to look at the hibernate sql, and using db to look at the results, I was immediately grasp the solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Please post solutions as an answer and accept it, rather than putting it in the question  Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Hibernate SQL, I realized that it was only querying for columns belonging in program_video.
So I used `Projection.fields` method to customize each columns of the output

## Solution

So I made a DTO like below

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProgramVideoAndProgressResponseDto {
    private String title;
    private String videoThumbnail;
    private String videoLength;
    private String watchedTo;
    private CompletionStatus completionStatus;
```

and Implemented this into my querydsl query:

```
        return queryFactory
                .select(Projections.fields(ProgramVideoAndProgressResponseDto.class,
                        programVideo.title,
                        programVideo.videoThumbnail,
                        videoRecordHistory.videoLength,
                        videoRecordHistory.watchedTo
                        ))
                .from(programVideo)
                .leftJoin(videoRecordHistory)
                .on(programVideo.eq(videoRecordHistory.programVideo)
                        .and(videoRecordHistory.memberId.eq(memberId))
                )
                .where(
                        programVideo.program.id.eq(programId)
                )
                .fetch();
    }
```